# Set project root folder

Tags: c++, makefile

I have c++ `Makefile` project. Project simplified folder looks as below:

```
 tmp|
    |--Makefile
    |--lvgl
    |  |--lvgl.h
    |--lv_drivers
    |  |--display
    |     |--fbdev.h
```

Unit `fbdev.h` contains include:

```
#include "lvgl/lvgl.h"
```

I have error while build related to this include:

```
lvgl/lvgl.h: No such file or directory
```

How to ask build system to find `lvgl/lvgl.h` by searching from from project root folder. Should I somehow define in `Makefile` project root location?

Autogenerated Makefile:

```
#Generated by VisualGDB project wizard. 
#Note: VisualGDB will automatically update this file when you add new sources to the project.
#All other changes you make in this file will be preserved.
#Visit http://visualgdb.com/makefiles for more details

#VisualGDB: AutoSourceFiles     #<--- remove this line to disable auto-updating of SOURCEFILES and EXTERNAL_LIBS

TARGETNAME := boilerX
#TARGETTYPE can be APP, STATIC or SHARED
TARGETTYPE := APP

to_lowercase = $(subst A,a,$(subst B,b,$(subst C,c,$(subst D,d,$(subst E,e,$(subst F,f,$(subst G,g,$(subst H,h,$(subst I,i,$(subst J,j,$(subst K,k,$(subst L,l,$(subst M,m,$(subst N,n,$(subst O,o,$(subst P,p,$(subst Q,q,$(subst R,r,$(subst S,s,$(subst T,t,$(subst U,u,$(subst V,v,$(subst W,w,$(subst X,x,$(subst Y,y,$(subst Z,z,$1))))))))))))))))))))))))))

macros-to-preprocessor-directives = $(foreach __macro, $(strip $1), \
    $(if $(findstring =,$(__macro)), \
        --pd "$(firstword $(subst =, ,$(__macro))) SETA $(subst ",\",$(lastword $(subst =, ,$(__macro))))", \
        --pd "$(__macro) SETA 1")) \

CONFIG ?= DEBUG

CONFIGURATION_FLAGS_FILE := $(call to_lowercase,$(CONFIG)).mak
TOOLCHAIN_ROOT ?= $(toolchain_root)

include $(CONFIGURATION_FLAGS_FILE)

#LINKER_SCRIPT defined inside the configuration file (e.g. debug.mak) should override any linker scripts defined in shared .mak files
CONFIGURATION_LINKER_SCRIPT := $(LINKER_SCRIPT)

include $(ADDITIONAL_MAKE_FILES)

ifneq ($(CONFIGURATION_LINKER_SCRIPT),)
LINKER_SCRIPT := $(CONFIGURATION_LINKER_SCRIPT)
endif

ifneq ($(LINKER_SCRIPT),)

ifeq ($(TOOLCHAIN_SUBTYPE),iar)
LDFLAGS += --config $(LINKER_SCRIPT)
else
LDFLAGS += -T$(LINKER_SCRIPT)
endif

endif

ifeq ($(AS),)
AS := as
endif

ifeq ($(AS),as)
AS := $(CC)
ASFLAGS := $(CFLAGS) $(ASFLAGS)
endif

ifeq ($(TOOLCHAIN_SUBTYPE),iar)
    CC_DEPENDENCY_FILE_SPECIFIER := --dependencies=m
    ASM_DEPENDENCY_FILE_SPECIFIER := && echo > 
    CXXFLAGS += --c++
    COMMONFLAGS += --silent

else ifeq ($(TOOLCHAIN_SUBTYPE),armcc)
    CC_DEPENDENCY_FILE_SPECIFIER := --depend
    ASM_DEPENDENCY_FILE_SPECIFIER := --depend
    USING_KEIL_TOOLCHAIN := 1
else ifeq ($(TOOLCHAIN_SUBTYPE),armclang)
    CC_DEPENDENCY_FILE_SPECIFIER := -MD -MF
    ASM_DEPENDENCY_FILE_SPECIFIER := --depend
    USING_KEIL_TOOLCHAIN := 1
else
    CC_DEPENDENCY_FILE_SPECIFIER := -MD -MF
    ASM_DEPENDENCY_FILE_SPECIFIER := -MD -MF
endif


ifeq ($(BINARYDIR),)
error:
    $(error Invalid configuration, please check your inputs)
endif

SOURCEFILES := boiler.cpp boilerX.cpp boiler_ui.cpp lvgl/examples/porting/lv_port_disp_template.c lvgl/examples/porting/lv_port_fs_template.c lvgl/examples/porting/lv_port_indev_template.c lvgl/src/lv_core/lv_disp.c lvgl/src/lv_core/lv_group.c lvgl/src/lv_core/lv_indev.c lvgl/src/lv_core/lv_obj.c lvgl/src/lv_core/lv_refr.c lvgl/src/lv_core/lv_style.c lvgl/src/lv_draw/lv_draw_arc.c lvgl/src/lv_draw/lv_draw_blend.c lvgl/src/lv_draw/lv_draw_img.c lvgl/src/lv_draw/lv_draw_label.c lvgl/src/lv_draw/lv_draw_line.c lvgl/src/lv_draw/lv_draw_mask.c lvgl/src/lv_draw/lv_draw_rect.c lvgl/src/lv_draw/lv_draw_triangle.c lvgl/src/lv_draw/lv_img_buf.c lvgl/src/lv_draw/lv_img_cache.c lvgl/src/lv_draw/lv_img_decoder.c lvgl/src/lv_font/lv_font.c lvgl/src/lv_font/lv_font_dejavu_16_persian_hebrew.c lvgl/src/lv_font/lv_font_fmt_txt.c lvgl/src/lv_font/lv_font_loader.c lvgl/src/lv_font/lv_font_montserrat_10.c lvgl/src/lv_font/lv_font_montserrat_12.c lvgl/src/lv_font/lv_font_montserrat_12_subpx.c lvgl/src/lv_font/lv_font_montserrat_14.c lvgl/src/lv_font/lv_font_montserrat_16.c lvgl/src/lv_font/lv_font_montserrat_18.c lvgl/src/lv_font/lv_font_montserrat_20.c lvgl/src/lv_font/lv_font_montserrat_22.c lvgl/src/lv_font/lv_font_montserrat_24.c lvgl/src/lv_font/lv_font_montserrat_26.c lvgl/src/lv_font/lv_font_montserrat_28.c lvgl/src/lv_font/lv_font_montserrat_28_compressed.c lvgl/src/lv_font/lv_font_montserrat_30.c lvgl/src/lv_font/lv_font_montserrat_32.c lvgl/src/lv_font/lv_font_montserrat_34.c lvgl/src/lv_font/lv_font_montserrat_36.c lvgl/src/lv_font/lv_font_montserrat_38.c lvgl/src/lv_font/lv_font_montserrat_40.c lvgl/src/lv_font/lv_font_montserrat_42.c lvgl/src/lv_font/lv_font_montserrat_44.c lvgl/src/lv_font/lv_font_montserrat_46.c lvgl/src/lv_font/lv_font_montserrat_48.c lvgl/src/lv_font/lv_font_montserrat_8.c lvgl/src/lv_font/lv_font_simsun_16_cjk.c lvgl/src/lv_font/lv_font_unscii_16.c lvgl/src/lv_font/lv_font_unscii_8.c lvgl/src/lv_gpu/lv_gpu_nxp_pxp.c lvgl/src/lv_gpu/lv_gpu_nxp_pxp_osa.c lvgl/src/lv_gpu/lv_gpu_nxp_vglite.c lvgl/src/lv_gpu/lv_gpu_stm32_dma2d.c lvgl/src/lv_hal/lv_hal_disp.c lvgl/src/lv_hal/lv_hal_indev.c lvgl/src/lv_hal/lv_hal_tick.c lvgl/src/lv_misc/lv_anim.c lvgl/src/lv_misc/lv_area.c lvgl/src/lv_misc/lv_async.c lvgl/src/lv_misc/lv_bidi.c lvgl/src/lv_misc/lv_color.c lvgl/src/lv_misc/lv_debug.c lvgl/src/lv_misc/lv_fs.c lvgl/src/lv_misc/lv_gc.c lvgl/src/lv_misc/lv_ll.c lvgl/src/lv_misc/lv_log.c lvgl/src/lv_misc/lv_math.c lvgl/src/lv_misc/lv_mem.c lvgl/src/lv_misc/lv_printf.c lvgl/src/lv_misc/lv_task.c lvgl/src/lv_misc/lv_templ.c lvgl/src/lv_misc/lv_txt.c lvgl/src/lv_misc/lv_txt_ap.c lvgl/src/lv_misc/lv_utils.c lvgl/src/lv_themes/lv_theme.c lvgl/src/lv_themes/lv_theme_empty.c lvgl/src/lv_themes/lv_theme_material.c lvgl/src/lv_themes/lv_theme_mono.c lvgl/src/lv_themes/lv_theme_template.c lvgl/src/lv_widgets/lv_arc.c lvgl/src/lv_widgets/lv_bar.c lvgl/src/lv_widgets/lv_btn.c lvgl/src/lv_widgets/lv_btnmatrix.c lvgl/src/lv_widgets/lv_calendar.c lvgl/src/lv_widgets/lv_canvas.c lvgl/src/lv_widgets/lv_chart.c lvgl/src/lv_widgets/lv_checkbox.c lvgl/src/lv_widgets/lv_cont.c lvgl/src/lv_widgets/lv_cpicker.c lvgl/src/lv_widgets/lv_dropdown.c lvgl/src/lv_widgets/lv_gauge.c lvgl/src/lv_widgets/lv_img.c lvgl/src/lv_widgets/lv_imgbtn.c lvgl/src/lv_widgets/lv_keyboard.c lvgl/src/lv_widgets/lv_label.c lvgl/src/lv_widgets/lv_led.c lvgl/src/lv_widgets/lv_line.c lvgl/src/lv_widgets/lv_linemeter.c lvgl/src/lv_widgets/lv_list.c lvgl/src/lv_widgets/lv_msgbox.c lvgl/src/lv_widgets/lv_objmask.c lvgl/src/lv_widgets/lv_objx_templ.c lvgl/src/lv_widgets/lv_page.c lvgl/src/lv_widgets/lv_roller.c lvgl/src/lv_widgets/lv_slider.c lvgl/src/lv_widgets/lv_spinbox.c lvgl/src/lv_widgets/lv_spinner.c lvgl/src/lv_widgets/lv_switch.c lvgl/src/lv_widgets/lv_table.c lvgl/src/lv_widgets/lv_tabview.c lvgl/src/lv_widgets/lv_textarea.c lvgl/src/lv_widgets/lv_tileview.c lvgl/src/lv_widgets/lv_win.c lvgl/tests/lv_test_assert.c lvgl/tests/lv_test_core/lv_test_core.c lvgl/tests/lv_test_core/lv_test_font_loader.c lvgl/tests/lv_test_core/lv_test_obj.c lvgl/tests/lv_test_core/lv_test_style.c lvgl/tests/lv_test_fonts/font_1.c lvgl/tests/lv_test_fonts/font_2.c lvgl/tests/lv_test_fonts/font_3.c lvgl/tests/lv_test_main.c lvgl/tests/lv_test_widgets/lv_test_label.c
EXTERNAL_LIBS := 
EXTERNAL_LIBS_COPIED := $(foreach lib, $(EXTERNAL_LIBS),$(BINARYDIR)/$(notdir $(lib)))

CFLAGS += $(COMMONFLAGS)
CXXFLAGS += $(COMMONFLAGS)
ASFLAGS += $(COMMONFLAGS)
LDFLAGS += $(COMMONFLAGS)

CFLAGS += $(addprefix -I,$(INCLUDE_DIRS))
CXXFLAGS += $(addprefix -I,$(INCLUDE_DIRS))

CFLAGS += $(addprefix -D,$(PREPROCESSOR_MACROS))
CXXFLAGS += $(addprefix -D,$(PREPROCESSOR_MACROS))

ifeq ($(USING_KEIL_TOOLCHAIN),1)
    ASFLAGS +=$(call macros-to-preprocesor-directives, $(PREPROCESSOR_MACROS))
else ifeq ($(TOOLCHAIN_SUBTYPE),iar)
    ASFLAGS := $(subst --cpu=,--cpu ,$(ASFLAGS))
    ASFLAGS := $(subst --fpu=,--fpu ,$(ASFLAGS))
    ASFLAGS := $(subst --silent,-S ,$(ASFLAGS))
    ASFLAGS += $(addprefix -D,$(PREPROCESSOR_MACROS))
else
    ASFLAGS += $(addprefix -D,$(PREPROCESSOR_MACROS))
endif

CXXFLAGS += $(addprefix -framework ,$(MACOS_FRAMEWORKS))
CFLAGS += $(addprefix -framework ,$(MACOS_FRAMEWORKS))
LDFLAGS += $(addprefix -framework ,$(MACOS_FRAMEWORKS))

LDFLAGS += $(addprefix -L,$(LIBRARY_DIRS))

ifeq ($(GENERATE_MAP_FILE),1)
LDFLAGS += -Wl,-Map=$(BINARYDIR)/$(basename $(TARGETNAME)).map
endif

LIBRARY_LDFLAGS = $(addprefix -l,$(LIBRARY_NAMES))

ifeq ($(IS_LINUX_PROJECT),1)
    RPATH_PREFIX := -Wl,--rpath='$$ORIGIN/../
    LIBRARY_LDFLAGS += $(EXTERNAL_LIBS)
    LIBRARY_LDFLAGS += -Wl,--rpath='$$ORIGIN'
    LIBRARY_LDFLAGS += $(addsuffix ',$(addprefix $(RPATH_PREFIX),$(dir $(EXTERNAL_LIBS))))
    
    ifeq ($(TARGETTYPE),SHARED)
        CFLAGS += -fPIC
        CXXFLAGS += -fPIC
        ASFLAGS += -fPIC
        LIBRARY_LDFLAGS += -Wl,-soname,$(TARGETNAME)
    endif
    
    ifneq ($(LINUX_PACKAGES),)
        PACKAGE_CFLAGS := $(foreach pkg,$(LINUX_PACKAGES),$(shell pkg-config --cflags $(pkg)))
        PACKAGE_LDFLAGS := $(foreach pkg,$(LINUX_PACKAGES),$(shell pkg-config --libs $(pkg)))
        CFLAGS += $(PACKAGE_CFLAGS)
        CXXFLAGS += $(PACKAGE_CFLAGS)
        LIBRARY_LDFLAGS += $(PACKAGE_LDFLAGS)
    endif   
else
    LIBRARY_LDFLAGS += $(EXTERNAL_LIBS)
endif

LIBRARY_LDFLAGS += $(ADDITIONAL_LINKER_INPUTS)

all_make_files := $(firstword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)) $(CONFIGURATION_FLAGS_FILE) $(ADDITIONAL_MAKE_FILES)

ifeq ($(STARTUPFILES),)
    all_source_files := $(SOURCEFILES)
else
    all_source_files := $(STARTUPFILES) $(filter-out $(STARTUPFILES),$(SOURCEFILES))
endif

source_obj1 := $(all_source_files:.cpp=.o)
source_obj2 := $(source_obj1:.c=.o)
source_obj3 := $(source_obj2:.s=.o)
source_obj4 := $(source_obj3:.S=.o)
source_obj5 := $(source_obj4:.cc=.o)
source_objs := $(source_obj5:.cxx=.o)

all_objs := $(addprefix $(BINARYDIR)/, $(notdir $(source_objs)))

PRIMARY_OUTPUTS :=

ifeq ($(GENERATE_BIN_FILE),1)
PRIMARY_OUTPUTS += $(BINARYDIR)/$(basename $(TARGETNAME)).bin
endif

ifeq ($(GENERATE_IHEX_FILE),1)
PRIMARY_OUTPUTS += $(BINARYDIR)/$(basename $(TARGETNAME)).ihex
endif

ifeq ($(PRIMARY_OUTPUTS),)
PRIMARY_OUTPUTS := $(BINARYDIR)/$(TARGETNAME)
endif

all: $(PRIMARY_OUTPUTS)

ifeq ($(USING_KEIL_TOOLCHAIN),1)

$(BINARYDIR)/$(basename $(TARGETNAME)).bin: $(BINARYDIR)/$(TARGETNAME)
    $(OBJCOPY) --bin $< --output $@

$(BINARYDIR)/$(basename $(TARGETNAME)).ihex: $(BINARYDIR)/$(TARGETNAME)
    $(OBJCOPY) --i32 $< --output $@

else ifeq ($(TOOLCHAIN_SUBTYPE),iar)

$(BINARYDIR)/$(basename $(TARGETNAME)).bin: $(BINARYDIR)/$(TARGETNAME)
    $(OBJCOPY) --silent --bin $< $@

$(BINARYDIR)/$(basename $(TARGETNAME)).ihex: $(BINARYDIR)/$(TARGETNAME)
    $(OBJCOPY) --silent --bin $< $@

else

$(BINARYDIR)/$(basename $(TARGETNAME)).bin: $(BINARYDIR)/$(TARGETNAME)
    $(OBJCOPY) -O binary $< $@

$(BINARYDIR)/$(basename $(TARGETNAME)).ihex: $(BINARYDIR)/$(TARGETNAME)
    $(OBJCOPY) -O ihex $< $@

endif
    
EXTRA_DEPENDENCIES :=

ifneq ($(LINKER_SCRIPT),)
EXTRA_DEPENDENCIES += $(LINKER_SCRIPT)
endif

ifeq ($(TARGETTYPE),APP)
$(BINARYDIR)/$(TARGETNAME): $(all_objs) $(EXTERNAL_LIBS) $(EXTRA_DEPENDENCIES)
ifeq ($(DETACH_CODE_COVERAGE),1)
    $(VISUALGDB_DIR)/VisualGDB.exe /decover $@ $(all_objs)
endif
    $(LD) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $(START_GROUP) $(all_objs) $(LIBRARY_LDFLAGS) $(END_GROUP)
endif

ifeq ($(TARGETTYPE),SHARED)
$(BINARYDIR)/$(TARGETNAME): $(all_objs) $(EXTERNAL_LIBS) $(EXTRA_DEPENDENCIES)
    $(LD) -shared -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $(START_GROUP) $(all_objs) $(LIBRARY_LDFLAGS) $(END_GROUP)
endif
    
ifeq ($(TARGETTYPE),STATIC)
$(BINARYDIR)/$(TARGETNAME): $(all_objs) $(EXTRA_DEPENDENCIES)
    $(AR) -r $@ $^
endif

-include $(all_objs:.o=.dep)

clean:
ifeq ($(USE_DEL_TO_CLEAN),1)
    cmd /C del /S /Q $(BINARYDIR)
else
    rm -rf $(BINARYDIR)
endif

$(BINARYDIR):
    mkdir $(BINARYDIR)

#VisualGDB: FileSpecificTemplates       #<--- VisualGDB will use the following lines to define rules for source files in subdirectories
$(BINARYDIR)/%.o : %.cpp $(all_make_files) |$(BINARYDIR)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ $(CC_DEPENDENCY_FILE_SPECIFIER) $(@:.o=.dep)

$(BINARYDIR)/%.o : %.c $(all_make_files) |$(BINARYDIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ $(CC_DEPENDENCY_FILE_SPECIFIER) $(@:.o=.dep)

$(BINARYDIR)/%.o : %.S $(all_make_files) |$(BINARYDIR)
    $(AS) $(ASFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ $(ASM_DEPENDENCY_FILE_SPECIFIER) $(@:.o=.dep)

$(BINARYDIR)/%.o : %.s $(all_make_files) |$(BINARYDIR)
    $(AS) $(ASFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ $(ASM_DEPENDENCY_FILE_SPECIFIER) $(@:.o=.dep)

$(BINARYDIR)/%.o : %.cc $(all_make_files) |$(BINARYDIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ $(CC_DEPENDENCY_FILE_SPECIFIER) $(@:.o=.dep)

$(BINARYDIR)/%.o : %.cxx $(all_make_files) |$(BINARYDIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ $(CC_DEPENDENCY_FILE_SPECIFIER)F $(@:.o=.dep)

#VisualGDB: GeneratedRules              #<--- All lines below are auto-generated. Remove this line to suppress auto-generation of file rules.


$(BINARYDIR)/lv_port_disp_template.o : lvgl/examples/porting/lv_port_disp_template.c $(all_make_files) |$(BINARYDIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ $(CC_DEPENDENCY_FILE_SPECIFIER) $(@:.o=.dep)


$(BINARYDIR)/lv_port_fs_template.o : lvgl/examples/porting/lv_port_fs_template.c $(all_make_files) |$(BINARYDIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ $(CC_DEPENDENCY_FILE_SPECIFIER) $(@:.o=.dep)


$(BINARYDIR)/lv_port_indev_template.o : lvgl/examples/porting/lv_port_indev_template.c $(all_make_files) |$(BINARYDIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ $(CC_DEPENDENCY_FILE_SPECIFIER) $(@:.o=.dep)


$(BINARYDIR)/lv_disp.o : lvgl/src/lv_core/lv_disp.c $(all_make_files) |$(BINARYDIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ $(CC_DEPENDENCY_FILE_SPECIFIER) $(@:.o=.dep)


$(BINARYDIR)/lv_group.o : lvgl/src/lv_core/lv_group.c $(all_make_files) |$(BINARYDIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ $(CC_DEPENDENCY_FILE_SPECIFIER) $(@:.o=.dep)


$(BINARYDIR)/lv_indev.o : lvgl/src/lv_core/lv_indev.c $(all_make_files) |$(BINARYDIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ $(CC_DEPENDENCY_FILE_SPECIFIER) $(@:.o=.dep)


.............
```

Comment: Yes your include directory should be specified in your makefile. You should also post your makefile

Comment: CFLAGS += $(addprefix -I,$(INCLUDE_DIRS))
CXXFLAGS += $(addprefix -I,$(INCLUDE_DIRS)) this is the relevant part

Comment: How to know what include dirs ae currently set?

Comment: That's one heck of an ugly Makefile. I would add echo targets that echo out some of those values being set. I'd make sure that there was a "-I ." (minus-eye-dot) argument in CXXFLAGS so that the top level directory was in the include search path.

Comment: Generated makefiles are like most generated scripts: huge, hideous, and practically impossible to maintain. Even if you manage to fix it, there's no way to push those changes back to the generator. Either adjust the generator to function correctly, or abandon it for good and write a new makefile by hand.